# notify-send giving syntax error with my custom Python file in 22.04

Tags: python, 22.04, notify-send

When I run a simple .py file with code

```
notify-send " ha ha "
```

I get notifications in 22.04 without any issues.

Then I tried the following code in another .py file. And it is giving a syntax error.

```
x = 1
count = x

while count <= 8:

    notify-send "Let's Take a Break!"
  
    
      
    sleep 60   

    count += 1 

    if count <= 8:        
        notify-send "Ok folks," "Let's get back to work!" 
    
        sleep 3600
else:
    notify-send "Ok folks," "Let's call it a day!"
```

Please help me identify the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to execute system commands like `notify-send` from within python scripts, you'll need to first import the `os` module then use it to execute that system command like so:

```py
import os

os.system('notify-send "Let\'s Take a Break!"')
```

That being said, you might need to pay attention to other syntax issues like the `sleep 60` call that might work in `bash` but python needs `time.sleep(60)` and you might want to first import the `time` module for that to work. Another thing is the indentation of `if` ... `else`, you need to pay attention to that too.

Therefore, the example code in your question should be:

```py
import os
import time

x = 1
count = x

while count <= 8:
    os.system('notify-send "Let\'s Take a Break!"')
    time.sleep(60)
    count += 1

    if count <= 8:
        os.system('notify-send "Ok folks," "Let\'s get back to work!"')
        time.sleep(3600)
    else:
        os.system('notify-send "Ok folks," "Let\'s call it a day!"')
```

It is very important as well to correctly run your python script with `python` and not other interpreters like e.g. `bash` as I understand from this(*which is most likely run by your shell e.g. `bash` and not the `python` interpreter*):

> When I run a simple .py file with code
>
> `notify-send " ha ha "`
>
> I get notifications in 22.04 without any issues.

Comment: Works great. As for the simple command, I just used " Allow this file to run as a program" in Properties and then right click " Run as a Program ".  For the original code, I tried `python3 code.py` without success.  Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to play a sound file after the notify send? I tried using a line with mpv filepath/filename.mp3, but it said " NameError: name 'mpv' is not defined ". Thanks.

Comment: @user227495 You might need to include the full path to the `mpv` executable  … or alternatively https://towardsdatascience.com/personalized-your-python-notification-sounds-with-chime-d04e803d7615?gi=f8cb93f35369

Comment: Thanks, looks like some issue with pip : `pip install chime
bash: /home/devel/.local/bin/pip: /snap/blender/2661/3.2/python/bin/python3.10: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: @user227495 You might need to first install `pip` if it's not installed with `sudo apt install python3-pip` ... also if mpv is installed on your system, it should work if run with the `os` module like so `os.system('mpv /path/to/file.mp3')` or any other program like VLC `os.system('vlc /path/to/file.mp3')`

Comment: Thanks, @Raffa , both issues are solved now. Worked exactly as you mentioned.