# Opening a new terminal from python script and running commands

Tags: python, gnome-terminal

I've included my code below. I would like to be able to launch a bash script as part of this python script below which launches a new terminal at a specific directory. The command I'd like to run is 'ls' once the new terminal is launched.

```
import subprocess
cmd = "gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/USERNAME/Documents/Scripts/"
subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Any ideas on how I might do that?

**This is my goal:**

- Upon running script.py from one terminal, I would like it to open a second terminal at a specific directory.
- Then, either execute a command1 + command2, or just run my bash.sh which has all of my commands already laid out.
- Leave the terminal open

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1434392

Comment: Not sure it quite addresses the use of subprocess however. Seems like they're using OS.ssytem. Any other ideas?